# Control dragging event to move to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Lets say that I have this simple HTML sctructure:

```
<header>
    <title>Test</title>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="section" id="section-1"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section-2"></div>
    <div class="section" id="section-3"></div>
</body>
```

... and this CSS style:

```
.section{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

#section-1{ background: red; }
#section-2{ background: green; }
#section-3{ background: blue; }
```

Here you can check it working: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMv2r/

I'm trying to find a way where the user can dragging this page vertically, and, depending where the user is, go to a specific div.

1 - If the user drag down in the red div, the scroll moves to the next one: green div. If the user drag up in the red div, continues in this div.

2 - If the user drag down in the green div, the scroll moves to the next one: blue div. If the user drag up in the green div, the scroll moves to the previous one: red div.

3 - If the user drag down in the blu div, continues in this div. If the user drag up in the blue div, the scroll moves to the previous one: green div.

I don't know where can I start doing these actions. I think that maybe jQuery UI can do something like this.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to do it using jquery ui drag&drop

Comment: @roasted But drag&drop won't make the divs draggable? I don't want this behavior...

Comment: You can apply draggable method to specific element. I just realize that i don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by: "I'm trying to find a way where the user can dragging this page vertically" ? Do you mean scrolling instead?

Comment: @roasted Like a touch device behavior, scrolling the page up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I would start here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FTouch_events

something like

```
function handleStart(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
var touches = evt.changedTouches;

for (var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
  ongoingTouches.push(touches[i]);
  var color = colorForTouch(touches[i]);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(touches[i].pageX-2, touches[i].pageY-2, 4, 4);
```

}
}